[Azure DevOps]: SourceLink or Symbol Server with Private Repo
Writing this because I've already spent an entire day trying to figure this out. Everything I could find in the web seems outdated.


The source code for our packages is stored in the Azure DevOps Repos.
We want to be able to debug our internal NuGet packages.
We don't want to embed the PDB files.

Things I tried:

Azure DevOps Symbol Server
SourceLink + Azure DevOps Symbol Server

None of these seem to work.
I would be very grateful if somebody could write down the step-by-step guide on how to properly configure what I want.
I've tried everything I could find in the docs, but it just sucks tbh.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/symbols?view=azure-devops
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/symbols?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#set-up-the-publish-task

Edit 1:
I have tried following the described steps in the docs, but no luck. I managed to make SourceLink work but only when the DebugType is set to embedded. But, as I said, we don’t want to include PDB files in the dll. After that, I tried to publish symbols to our internal Azure DevOps repo using the pipeline task provided in the docs, the task succeeded, but the symbols are not getting loaded when I start debugging in the VS (after configuring the Symbol server ofc). However, I get the decompiled, and then somehow it loads symbols of the decompiled. Idk what’s this
Edit 2:
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  inputs:
    SymbolsFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    SearchPattern: '**/bin/**/*.pdb'
    IndexSources: false
    PublishSymbols: true
    SymbolServerType: 'TeamServices' 
    SymbolExpirationInDays: '36530'
    IndexableFileFormats: 'Default'
    DetailedLog: true
    SymbolsArtifactName: 'Symbols_$(BuildConfiguration)'

Edit 3:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
        <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
</Project>


"None of these seem to work" - could you please elaborate on that?

@RuiJarimba sure. So I have tried following the described steps in the docs, but no luck. I managed to make SourceLink work but only when the DebugType is set to embedded. But, as I said, we don’t want to include PDB files in the dll. After that, I tried to publish symbols to our internal Azure DevOps repo using the pipeline task provided in the docs, the task succeeded, but the symbols are not getting loaded when I start debugging in the VS (after configuring the Symbol server ofc). However, I get the decompiled, and then somehow it loads symbols of the decompiled. Idk what’s this

@desmondische, What do you mean "I tried to publish symbols to our internal Azure DevOps repo"? Please provide the detailed YAML of your pipeline which includes this step. As far as I know, the PublishSymbols only support publishing symbol files to Azure Artifacts symbol server (TeamServices) and a File share (FileShare). It does not support publishing to Azure Repos.

@desmondische, The PDB files are the symbol files used to link from Visual Studio to the source code to debug the application. If you do not include PDB files when publishing symbols, how you link to the source code? Again, please provide the detailed YAML of your pipeline, and the detailed steps and screenshots to show what you have done. Explain what detailed issue are facing, or which step you are stuck at currently?

@BrightRan-MSFT My bad. I actually meant Azure DevOps Artifacts. Updated the post with the YAML file. It is the basic template + the task to publish symbols provided in the MS docs.

@BrightRan-MSFT I am not sure if the pipeline build configuration should be set to Debug. During testing I explicitly set the DebugType in the project to portable, and the PublishSymbols task did not complain.

@BrightRan-MSFT Included the project file, too.

Managed to configure SourceLink + Azure DevOps Symbols Server with the help of this video:
No need for additional project file configurations if .NET version is >= 8
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Azure DevOps pipeline YAML file
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs: 
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj' 
    versioningScheme: 'byPrereleaseNumber'
    majorVersion: '1'
    minorVersion: '0'
    patchVersion: '0'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs: 
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'c4a7af6d-9593-4a8f-ab27-07194500dea0'

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**/bin/**/*.pdb'
    IndexSources: false
    SymbolServerType: 'TeamServices'

VS Debugging settings

[ ] Enable Just My Code
[x] Enable source server support
[x] Enable Source Link support

Don't forget to grant the necessary access permissions to your project build service in your feed's settings. I've spent some time until I figured why the Push task was failing all the time.
Artifacts -> YourFeed -> Feed Settings (gear icon) -> Permissions -> Add users/groups. Start typing your project's name, and it will appear there as "YourProjectName Build Service (YourOrgName)". Grant it the Feed Publisher permissions.

Glad to see the issue can be fixed, and thanks for sharing the answer. Maybe, you can accept this answer by yourself. It could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar questions. @desmondische

@BrightRan-MSFT Thank you for reminding to accept it as an answer. Completely forgot to..
